# How to display all rows in a MySQL table with a specific column value?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to output all rows of a MySQL table using PHP, but I only want to output rows where my `code_author` column has a specific value. I researched online for a few hours, but I've only been able to output ALL rows (not filter based on if a column has a value).

The rows should only be outputted if the `code_author` column matches that author of who is logged in, so the variable `$phpro_username` does already pull the username. The code below outputs the following: ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound. However if I remove the `WHERE code_author = :$phpro_username` part, it does output ALL of the rows perfectly fine, but that's not what I'm trying to achieve.  Any idea on how to fix this up?

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
$stmt2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM qr_codes WHERE code_author = :$phpro_username");
try {
    $stmt2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM qr_codes");
    $stmt2->execute();
    $result = $stmt2->fetchAll();

    if ( count($result) ) { 
        foreach($result as $row) {
            print_r($row);
        }   
    } 
    else {
        echo "No rows returned.";
    }
} 
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: `$dbh = new PDO` is connection, not query. Plus, `:$` that doesn't make any sense. Use a variable, **or** a placeholder; not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialization of PDO object is to provide your datasource name and user credentials.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name', 'username', 'password');
```

And you shouldn't use your interpolated variables in your statement preparation. You should put a named placedholder:

```
$stmt2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM qr_codes WHERE code_author = :phpro_username");
$stmt2->bindParam(':phpro_username', $phpro_username);
$stmt2->execute();
```

Then just follow it up with your fetching:

```
$results = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($results);
foreach($results as $row) {
    echo $row['your_column_name'];
    // and others
}
```